# Setting wait seconds on require with grunt

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gruntjs, require

I am running into load timeout errors with Require on my app. I'm building my require files with grunt and the require optimizer. I have set a waitseconds and have seen the timeouts go away on my local, but it's still occurring in prod. I have set my waitseconds in my grunt file, but also tried my main js file, but don't see where they get pushed to the active script files. Does anyone know where I can find this value in prod? It doesn't get written to the require.js file when grunt runs the task, and it's not included in my main.js file when require and optimizer run. Where does the browser pick up this value? I see the initial 7 seconds timeout in the require.js file on prod, but can't find where my option gets picked up.

Here's my require grunt task:

```
 requirejs: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: ".",
            appDir: "js",
            waitSeconds: 40,
            findNestedDependencies: true,
            mainConfigFile: "js/common.js",
            dir: "../assets/js",
            paths: {
                "rs": "mains/recordsearch"
            },
            optimize: "none",
            // modules to be optimized and bundled
            // "include" and "exclude" can be used here
            // to add or ignore dependencies
            modules: [{
                name: "common"
            }, {
                name: "rs/home"
            }, {
                name: "commons/html5shim"
            }]
        },
        dev: {},
        prod: {
            options: {
                optimize: "uglify"
            }
        }
    },
```

and my "main" require js page:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
    // libraries path
    "jquery": "libs/jquery",
    "jquery-ui": "libs/jquery-ui",
    "modernizr": "libs/modernizr.custom",

    // validation
    "boolean": "validation/custom/boolean",
    "comparefield": "validation/custom/comparefield",
    "expirationdate": "validation/custom/expirationdate",
    "securitycode": "validation/custom/securitycode",
    "fullname": "validation/custom/fullname",
    "zip": "validation/custom/zip",
    "ajaxval": "validation/framework/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min",
    "vsdoc": "validation/framework/jquery.validate-vsdoc",
    "validate": "validation/framework/jquery.validate.min",
    "unobtrusive": "validation/framework/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min",

    // plugins
    "acmodal": "plugins/acmodal",
    "acbutton": "plugins/acbutton",
    "acnav": "plugins/acnav",
    "actooltip": "plugins/actooltip",

    // utils and polyfills
    "bridge": "utils/pluginbridge",
    "object.create": "polyfills/object.create",
    "counter": "utils/counter",

    // funnels
    "rs": "mains/recordsearch"
},
// The shim section allows you to specify 
// dependencies between non AMD compliant files.
shim: {
    "jquery": {
        exports: "$"
    },
    "modernizr": {},
    "acbutton": ["jquery", "object.create", "bridge"],
    "acnav": ["jquery", "object.create", "bridge", "modernizr"],
    "acmodal": ["jquery", "object.create", "bridge", "jquery-ui"],
    "actooltip": ["jquery", "object.create", "bridge", "counter"],
    "ajaxval": ["validate", "unobtrusive", "boolean", "comparefield", "expirationdate", "comparefield", "boolean", "fullname", "zip", "securitycode"]
},
});

require([
"jquery",
"ajaxval",
"actooltip",
"acbutton",
"acnav",
"acmodal",
"commons/errorhandling"
], function () {

//waiting until dom is loaded to load the page modules
$(function () {
    // the start module is defined on the body tag.
    // example: <body data-jspage="rs/main"> or <body data-jspage="rs/main, rs/common">
    var startModule = $("body").attr("data-jspage");
    var siteArea = $("body").attr("data-area");

    if (startModule) {
        require([startModule]);
    }
    if (siteArea === "FE") {
        require(["commons/signin"]);
    }
 });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further testing, I figured out that waitSeconds has to go into the mainconfigFile, in this case, the "main" js that I posted above. It is read into the page from that file, which is in production, as opposed to the gruntfile. If you put the waitSeconds option into the gruntfile, it will not work unless perhaps you are running your site in node. Not certain in what cases it works, although the grunt-require-contrib documentation states it as an option. I looked through the r.js script from the grunt node package, and nothing that I would change in that file would affect anything that went to my output files, only the optimization and bundling. I ran some tests by passing the waitSeconds value to my error and found that changing the value in the mainconfigFile shows up in the browser, but any changes in the gruntfile task did nothing. Hope this helps someone else.